# not able to assert the updated value in tests spring boot jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to perform update with NamedQuery but updated values are not getting persisted in the DB though the update statement returning the updated count. This is happening only in tests but in the actual flow update is happening.

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public void test() throws Exception 
  messageHandler.process(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new Exception();
}
assertEquals(new Integer(5), ServiceImpl.findById(100L).get().getStatus());
}

Class MessageHandler{
   @Transactional
   public void process(String message){
       serviceImpl.update(5,100, some date, user);
   }
}

class ServiceImpl {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
public void updateOrderStatus(Integer newOrderStatus, Long OrderId, String updateTs,
  String updateUserId) {
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Order.UPDATE_ORDER_STATUS);
entityManager.flush();
query.setParameter(1, newOrderStatus);
query.setParameter(2, OrderId);
query.setParameter(3, updateTs);
query.setParameter(4, updateUserId);
int i = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("***************************************");
System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong in testcases?

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

By default test transactions are rolled back. You'll need to explicitly use @Commit if you want your tests to commit the changes. If you haven't already, take a look at the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-rollback-and-commit-behavior).